# Jpa custom query to copy data from a table to another table

Tags: spring

I am newbie in Jpa. I want to copy data from a table to another (courses to course_confirm). However, I get response from both the browser and console: No message available java.lang.NullPointerException. I will like somebody to help me out. Followings are some of the codes:

1. The repository:

   ```
    public interface MoveCourseRepository extends JpaRepository<CourseCh, Long>{

    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT course_code, "
            + "credit_unit, dept_id, joint_prerequisite, pass_mark, first_prerequisite, "
            + "second_preriquisite, semester, session, course_title, course_type, created_at, "
            + "updated_at from courses")
    Set<CourseCh> moveCourseConfirm();
   ```

   }
2. course_confirm and courses entity class have the same fields:

   @Entity

   ```
    @Table(name = "course_confirm")
    public class CourseCh extends AuditModel{

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @Column(name = "id")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private long id;

        @NotEmpty(message = "course code required")
        @Column(name = "course_code")
        private String code;

        @NotEmpty(message = "Course title required")
        @Column(name = "course_title")
        private String title;

        @NotEmpty(message = "Department required")
        @Column(name = "dept_id")
        private String deptid;

        @NotEmpty(message = "Credit units required")
        @Column(name = "credit_unit")
        private String creditunit;

        @Column(name = "semester")
        private String semester;

        @Column(name = "course_type")
        private String type;

        @NotEmpty(message = "Pass mark required")
        @Column(name = "pass_mark")
        private String passmark;

        @NotEmpty(message = "Session required")
        @Column(name = "session")
        private String session;

        @Column(name = "first_prerequisite")
        private String prerequisite1;

        @Column(name = "second_preriquisite")
        private String prerequisite2;

        @Column(name = "joint_prerequisite")
        private String jointprerequisite;
    //No argument, all arguments constructor and toString omitted for bravity
   ```
3. Service layer:

   public CourseCh saveCourseConfirm() {
   Set allDataList = moveCourseRepository.moveCourseConfirm();
   CourseCh courseCh = new CourseCh();
   for(CourseCh  courseChObj : allDataList) {
   moveCourseRepository.save(courseChObj);
   courseCh = courseChObj;
   }
   return courseCh;
   }
4. Method to save in the controller

   @PostMapping("/approveCurriculum")
   public String createCourseCh() {

   ```
        courseChService.saveCourseConfirm();
        return "redirect:/";
    }
   ```

The select statement executed successfully but jpa could not save the fetched data from course to course_confirm table.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using set to retrieve all the values you can basically use a custom query to sort this issue out in a easiest way. Just use the query given below and pass the id value which has the last inserted id so that duplicate values wont be used again and again to be inserted.

```
insert into course_confirm select * from course where id > 1
```

Comment: Thank you Muthukumaran for your time response to my question. However, I will like to inform you that I tried the suggestion you made but I got response from the server saying "Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "{id}"".  I will post again the update I made to the code bellow:

Answer (score 0):

Following is update I effected on aforementioned code:

1. The repository layer:

   @Repository
   public interface MoveCourseRepository extends CrudRepository<CourseCh, Long>{

   ```
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "INSERT into course_confirm SELECT * FROM courses WHERE id > 1")
    List<CourseCh> moveCourseConfirm(long id);
   ```

   }
2. The service layer:

   @Override
   public List saveCourseConfirm(long id) {
   return moveCourseRepository.moveCourseConfirm(id);
   }
3. The controller layer:

   @PostMapping("/approveCurriculum/{id}")
   public String createCourseCh(@PathVariable long id, Model  model) {
   model.addAttribute("course", courseChService.saveCourseConfirm(id));
   return "redirect:/course";
   }

Still, I get server response saying: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "{id}"

I will appreciate any input made to me.